# Add list of fragments on map marker click

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-listview, google-maps-markers

I need to do the following:
when the user click on the  map then the marker will be created on the map, as well as the list will be appeared.

each time the marker create then the list will add item related to this marker number.

the following snapshot shows what I need to do:
marker 1 created then fragment with number one appeared in the list that located on the bottom of the screen.

[image]

Actually I added the markers and save them in list, but how to add this dynamically list of fragments. I don't have any idea to this and with this layout to appeared in the bottom and have a nice style.

Answer (score 1):

1. First you have to use setOnMapClickListener to click on Map
2. Sec you have to use MarkerOptions class to add Marker on Map
3. You have to use a ArrayList to store all your markers
4. I don,t understand what kind of list you want.